# Measuring philoprimality/misoprimality

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, prime-gaps, prime-constellations

Given a natural integer $x$, let
$$\alpha(x)=(\log x)^2\sum_{p\in\mathcal P\setminus\{x\}}\frac{1}{(x-p)^2}$$
(with $\mathcal P$ denoting the set of prime-numbers)
measure its "philoprimality" which is large if $x$ has more than average close primes and which is small if $x$ is misoprimal (shy of prime numbers).

I guess that there should exist asymptotic averages
$$A_{\mathbb N}=\lim_{N\to \infty}\frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=1}^N\alpha(n)$$
(this  is wrong, see below)
and
$$A_{\mathcal P}=\lim_{N\to \infty} \frac{1}{\pi(N)}\sum_{p\in\mathcal P\cap[2,N]}\alpha(p)$$
(where $\pi(N)=\sharp(\mathcal P\cap[2,N])$ counts the number of primes up to $N$)
over all natural numbers, respectively over all prime-numbers.

Is there a reasonable guess for the values of $A_{\mathbb N}$ and $A_{\mathcal P}$? (I expect $A_{\mathcal P}$ to be strictly smaller than $A_{\mathbb N}$. Indeed, it lacks in some sense the main contribution.)

I guess, suitable normalizations of $\mu$ yield density-functions over
$\mathbb N$ or over $\mathcal P$ (The normalized value of $\mu$ should give the proportion of integers/primes which are at least as misoprimal as $x$). What are the correct normalizations?

Final Remarks: I believe that the obvious guess $A_{\mathcal P}=\frac{3}{\pi^2}$ is too naive.

It is of course also possible that these averages do not exist. This would however be even more surprising.

The choice of the the inverse of the squared distance is somewhat arbitrary. It is perhaps not the best choice.

(A choice where everything is probably straightforward is to work with the short-sighted function $\sigma(x)=\frac{\log x}{\mathrm{dist}(x,\mathcal P\setminus\{x\})}$ which considers only the distance to the closest prime distinct from $x$.)

**Added after Terry Tao's remark:** Terry Tao's remark works after modifying $A_{\mathbb N}$ and by considering the weighted mean
$$\begin{array}{rl}\tilde A_{\mathbb N}&=\lim_{N\to \infty} \frac{1}{N\log N}\sum_{n=1}^N \alpha(n)\\
&=\lim_{N\to \infty}\frac{1}{N\log N}\sum_{p\in\mathcal P}\sum_{n\in\{1,\ldots,N\}\setminus\{p\}}\frac{(\log n)^2}{(n-p)^2}\\
&=\lim_{N\to\infty} \frac{1}{N\log N}\sum_{p\in\mathcal P,\sqrt{N}<p<N-\sqrt{N}}\sum_{n\in\{1,\ldots,N\}\setminus\{p\}}\frac{(\log n)^n}{(n-p)^2}+C\\
&=\frac{\pi^2}{3}
\end{array}$$
which yields an expected mean value of $\pi^2/3$ for $\alpha(n)/\log (n)$.

I guess that one has to work with $A_{\mathcal P}$ when working with the expected value of $\alpha(p)$ for prime-numbers (and I do not know how to get an exact value for $A_{\mathcal P}$).

Comment: I'm confused by your notation $P\setminus\{x\}$, do you mean that to be the set of all primes $P$ which do not divide $x$?

Comment: No, $\mathcal P\setminus\{ x\}$ denotes the set of all primes different from $x$ (which is the set of all primes if $x$ is not a prime).

Comment: In number theory, especially in prime number theory, $\mu$ denotes the Möbius function. So I suggest that you replace $\mu$ in this post by another symbol. Similarly, $\sigma(x)$ usually stands for the sum of divisors of $x$.

Comment: And also the Latex command for the limit is \to, not \mapsto.

Comment: $A_N$ can be computed to high accuracy simply by interchanging the sums, evaluating the inner sum, and applying the prime number theorem.  $A_{\mathcal P}$ can be basically rearranged (using the change of variables $h = p-p'$, where $p,p'$ are the primes in question) in terms of the pair correlations $\frac{1}{x} \sum_{n \leq x} \Lambda(n) \Lambda(n+h)$ of the von Mangoldt function for $h \neq 0$, with the bulk of the contribution coming from $h=O(1)$.  Conjecturally, this can be controlled by the Hardy-Littlewood prime tuples conjecture; unconditionally, one can get reasonable upper bounds.